# python pandas pd.to_datetime

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set for call center agents and I want to calculate the average of each agent handling time.

I have the call duration but I tried to convert it to DateTime I have an error `TypeError: to_timedelta() got an unexpected keyword argument 'format'`

and sys

```
df['Interaction_Duration']
294    24:53
295    25:15
296    27:02
297    33:44
298    35:52
```

```py
df['Interaction_Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Interaction_Duration'],format='%M:%S')
```

result is

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-160-350e60e01ab7> in <module>
----> 1 df['Interaction_Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Interaction_Duration'],format='%M:%S')

TypeError: to_timedelta() got an unexpected keyword argument 'format'
```

Comment: can you provide what values are present in df['Interaction_Duration'] so that we will be able to understand what is the issue about

Comment: to_timedelta does not have an option format, it has unit, where you can specify days/hours/minutes. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html

Comment: 298    35:52
Name: Interaction_Duration, Length: 299, dtype: object

Comment: First, it is difficult to imagine what you are trying to compute given a single value for each agent.  Do you want the average time expressed as minutes, seconds, or as mins:secs?  Second, if you read the documentation for timedelta, you can easily see the problem is your call.  To begin, you must convert your time data to a pd.timestamp before you can do anything

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Interaction_Duration']


df['Interaction_Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Interaction_Duration'],format='%M:%S')
```

I data set for call center agents and I want to calculate the average of each agent handling time I have the call duration but I tried to convert it to DateTime I have an error (TypeError: to_timedelta() got an unexpected keyword argument 'format') and sys

Blockquote df['Interaction_Duration'] 294 24:53 295 25:15 296 27:02 297 33:44 298 35:52

enter code here
df['Interaction_Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Interaction_Duration'],format='%M:%S')

result is
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) in ----> 1 df['Interaction_Duration'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Interaction_Duration'],format='%M:%S')

TypeError: to_timedelta() got an unexpected keyword argument 'format'

Comment: you have to edit in question not in answer section

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are trying to do is compute the average time an agent defined by an ID spends on average on service calls.
Given a dataframe defined by:

```
import pandas as pd
dtin = [[294, '24:53'], 
        [295, '25:15'], 
        [296, '27:02'], 
        [297, '33:44'], 
        [298, '35:52'],
        [294, '18:33'], 
        [295, '16:25'], 
        [296, '11:02'], 
        [297, '20:44'], 
        [298, '19:52'],
        [294, '34:53'], 
        [295, '35:15'], 
        [296, '37:02'], 
        [297, '43:44'], 
        [298, '45:52']
       ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=dtin, columns = ['ID', 'Time'])
```

Step 1: Convert 'Time' column to Datetime by:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time"], format='%M:%S')
```

Step 2:  Add new column which expresses Time in min duration by:

```
df['T_dur'] = [x.minute + x.second/60 for x in df['Time'].to_list()]
```

step 3: Group data by ID by:

```
gb = df.groupby("ID")
```

step 4 Compute average T_dur for each agent by:

```
gb['T_dur'].mean()
```

which yields:

```
ID
294    26.105556
295    25.638889
296    25.033333
297    32.733333
298    33.866667
Name: T_dur, dtype: float64
```